# Python attrs package: validators after instantiation

Tags: python, validation, properties, attributes, attr

The attrs package for python provides a simple way to validate passed variables upon instantiation ([example taken from attrs page](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/init.html)):

```
>>> @attr.s
... class C(object):
...     x = attr.ib(validator=attr.validators.instance_of(int))
>>> C(42)
C(x=42)
>>> C("42")
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
TypeError: ("'x' must be <type 'int'> (got '42' that is a <type 'str'>).", Attribute(name='x', default=NOTHING, factory=NOTHING, validator=<instance_of validator for type <type 'int'>>, type=None), <type 'int'>, '42')
```

This works well, as the thrown exception proves. However, when I change the value of x after instantiation, no exception is thrown:

```
c = C(30)
c.x = '30'
```

For static objects this behavior can be OK, but it seems heavily dangerous to me to assume that an object is static. Is there a workaround to get validators with attrs that also work after instantiation?

Comment: Get rid of the `attrs` package (a typical "good idea that is actually not such a good idea") and use custom descriptors (computed attributes) doing the validation. My 2 cents...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way which keeps mutability is like so:

```
@attr.s
class C(object):

    _x = attr.ib(validator=attr.validators.instance_of(int))

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        assert isinstance(value, int), repr(value)  # or whatever error you want
        self._x = value
```

But even this is not safe against `c._x = '30'`.

The problem isn't with `attrs`, it's with python. `a.b = c` is always going to work when `a.b` is just a variable. This is due to pythons concept of "we're all consenting adults here" -- i.e. everything is public, and everything is modifiable. If you edit something you shouldn't, it's your fault.

That being said, `attrs` does provide a hack to prevent attribute assignment to give an illusion of immutability:

```
@attr.s(frozen=True)
class C(object):

    x = attr.ib(validator=attr.validators.instance_of(int))


 c = C(1)
 c.x = 30  # raises FrozenInstanceError
```

Comment: Don't use `assert` for production code, raise a proper exception instead (in this case reusing the validator would be the right thing to do). `assert` is really a developer tool, and is deactivated if code is compiled with -o flag.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I agree, but this is an example, not production code

Answer (score 3):

In [version 20.1.0](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html) they have added `on_setattr`:

> A callable that is run whenever the user attempts to set an attribute (either by assignment like i.x = 42 or by using setattr like setattr(i, "x", 42)). It receives the same arguments as validators: the instance, the attribute that is being modified, and the new value.

So, adding:

```
import attr

@attr.s
class C(object):
    x = attr.ib(
        validator=attr.validators.instance_of(int),
        on_setattr = attr.setters.validate,  # new in 20.1.0
    )
```

yields

```
C(42)
# C(x=42)
C("42")
#  TypeError: ("'x' must be <class 'int'>
```

Also, specifically for string input like in your example, you may find `attrs` converters handy. For example, to automatically convert:

```
@attr.s
class CWithConvert(object):
    x = attr.ib(
        converter=int,
        validator=attr.validators.instance_of(int),
        on_setattr = attr.setters.validate,
    )

CWithConvert(42)
# CWithConvert(x=42)
CWithConvert("42")
# CWithConvert(x=42)  # converted!
CWithConvert([42])
# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Careful though with:

```
CWithConvert(0.8)
# CWithConvert(x=0)  # float to int!
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [discussion in thread for `attrs`](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/109)

> So the original implementation of the validation code actually also
>   ran the validators on assignment.
>
> I’ve removed it before merging because in dynamic languages like
>   Python there’s just too many ways to circumvent it and I personally
>   prefer to not mutate my objects anyways. Hence attrs rich support for
>   freezing classes and creating new instances with changed attributes
>   (assoc).
>
> Of course you can add such a feature yourself by implementing a
>   **setattr** method that calls your validators whenever you try to set an attribute.

Comment: Thank you, this explains it. Although, I do not understand how programming without mutating objects works in any reasonable way.

Comment: @HeinzKurt It's called [functional programming](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/introduction-functional-programming-python/)

Comment: The corresponding design pattern is named "Value Object" (different names may exist). https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html